# HTML table complex header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Im pretty new to web dev, so please excuse my probable stupidity. and ive got a small display thing. I have a table with a table in it as one of the tds. I want the inner table part of it to have like a composite heading. In the example below the heading would be Hobbies, and the under it the headings of the hobbies table that would  NUMBER, HOBBY and DESCRIPTION. So if you look at the entire table the headings are NAME, SURNAME, JOB and then on a level higher HOBBIES with the sub headings on the same level as the first ones. I hope this makes sense. How can i achieve something like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Job</th>
        <th>Hobbies</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>McJohnson</td>
        <td>Dentist</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Lego</td>
                    <td>I like to play Lego</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: only html is tagged, so you just nest the tables as you have done, won't look that nice though. Tag your question with css, js and jquery and you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? could be styled better but you get the idea...you will have to use js I think if you want the heading moved up seperate from the second table

```css
td table{display:none;}
tr td:nth-child(4){background-color:gray;}
td:hover table{position:absolute;left:200px;background-color:yellow;display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Job</th>
        <th>Hobbies</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>McJohnson</td>
        <td>Dentist</td>
          <td>Hover Me
        
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Number</th>
                  <th>Hobby</th>
                  <th>Comment</th>
                 </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  
            
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Lego</td>
                    <td>I like to play Lego</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>McJohnson</td>
        <td>Dentist</td>
          <td>Hover Me
        
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Number</th>
                  <th>Hobby</th>
                  <th>Comment</th>
                 </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  
            
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Lego</td>
                    <td>I like to play Lego</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

/th

Comment: This isnt exactly what i was looking for but i very well might be able to do something like this thanks